# Why is my electorate badge not showing up?

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

I've just earned the Electorate badge on [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), but [my profile there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53251/ethan-bierlein) doesn't display it. For proof that I've actually earned the badge, here's a screenshot:

[image: Totally one day away from badge:fanatic. Much l33t.]

Why is the badge not showing up in my profile?

Comment: From my experience, it sometimes take a little time for the badge to be awarded

Comment: Just tested it out, for me it was about 1 hour and 15-30 minutes after I got the checkmark.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new profile tracker does put a checkmark on the badge once you *meet the requirements*.

*Awarding the badge* takes a bit longer, and, as far I can see, you've got it. So once you see such a checkmark, you can be sure the badge is already flying to you on the big wings.

Comment: Interesting, I have just got `Electorate` and one other badge just few minutes later. The newest is already listed on my profile, but the `Electorate` is not.